# Using Javascript to format an HTML string to display properly

Tags: javascript, java, html

The back end hands off a string that gets displayed like:

`"Hello, <br><br> This notice is to inform you that you are in violation of <font color=red><b>HR POLICY XXXXX</b></font>."`

The point of this page is to let you easily copy-paste pre-generated emails, but spewing out a bunch of html tags through the sentences is unwanted.

The string in question is inside of a  with an id of "textBlock".

The back end is Java with an Oracle DB. I can edit the java to some extent and I can't touch the DB at all. I've used the console to play around with the string and editing it in any way seems to make it display properly once I finish editing. The innerText includes tags like in my summary, the innerHTML displays the tags like <br>.

So far I've attempted to give the  an onload attribute that calls a function named formatText(); that does:
temp var = document.getElementById("textBlock").innerText;
document.getElementById("textBlock").innerText = var;

as well as the above function with innerHTML instead of innerText. I've also tried using document.write(); but that clears the rest of the page.Finally I've added some random characters in front of the string and tried to use the replace("!@#","") function to replace those in an effort to mimic the "editing it in any way seems to make it display properly" that I noticed.

java

`out.println("<td align=left id=textBlock onload=formatText();> !@#" + strTemp + "</td>" );`

Expected:

Hello,

This notice is to inform you that you are in violation of **HR POLICY XXXXX**.

Actual:

`Hello, <br><br> This notice is to inform you that you are in violation of <font color=red><b>HR POLICY XXXXX</b></font>.`

Comment: It seems like the HTML tags in the string aren't real HTML tags, but rather encoded with entities (`&lt;`, `&gt;`), which make them appear like HTML but not parsed as such. Have you checked the source string?

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("textBlock").innerHTML = The_String_That_You_Get_From_Backend;`

Comment: @Pantalaimon I got someone with DB access to check the DB and they are stored as <br>, <font color=red>, etc... NOT as encoded entities.

Comment: @Enzy I tried var placeholder = document.getElementById("textBlock"); document.getElementById("textBlock").innerHTML = placeholder.innerHTML; which should yield the same result. I've also tried innerText in place of innerHTML to see if that would make a difference. Neither worked :(

Comment: @CasinoRoyale is there any processing done on the output of the DB query that may alter it before `out.println`-ing the data? Or maybe you're using a procedure like `HTP.ESCAPE_SC` in your query?

Comment: @Pantalaimon I was going to say no, but I decided to double check and someone is overriding a function to replace stuff in the string with &quot, &lt, etc...I'm commenting that out and writing a new function to just change the " to &quot (so no issues at runtime by breaking a " early) coupled with some JS to change &quot back to ". Will update if this solves it

Comment: @Pantalaimon it's now formatting correctly (well the font color=red is showing up as green, but whatever). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you want, if I understood correctly, is some stripping html tags function. You can use regex

```js
var str = "Hello, <br><br> This notice is to inform you that you are in violation of <font color=red><b>HR POLICY XXXXX</b></font>."

console.log(str)

var str2 = str.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '')

console.log(str2)
```

If you want the html element to render your html, you need to use the DOM property `innerHtml`

```js
var str = "Hello, <br><br> This notice is to inform you that you are in violation of <font color=red><b>HR POLICY XXXXX</b></font>."

document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = str
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Hi</div>
```

Comment: I'd like for the tags to be read as html and cause text formatting rather than just a string with tags in it. I've updated the Actual vs Expected above to try and better reflect this

Comment: @CasinoRoyale edited accordingly. Is that ok? Any issues let me know

Answer (score 1):

(resolved in comments, answer added for completeness)

When HTML tags are visible in the browser, it's usually encoded with html-entities, preventing it getting parsed as HTML. In this case a post-processing script was replacing the `<` and `>` characters to their entity counterparts `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Disabling these replacements resolved the issue.